# What is the meaning of ようじゃね?

Tags: meaning

I didn't understand "**ようじゃね**" in this sentence.

大チャンスで ２分の１をはずす**ようじゃね**

Comment: Welcome to JL SE, and thanks for your first question! If you haven't already, please do have a look at the community guidelines in the Help Center (particularly: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As explained there, please could you please demonstrate your own research effort around your question? Otherwise, your question might be interpreted as a translation request, and would therefore be deemed "off-topic". If nothing else, showing your own research/understanding/attempt at the translation will enable others to better answer your question. Thanks and welcome again.

Answer (score 1):

> 大チャンスで2分の1をはずすよう**じゃね**。
> ***If*** he fails to grab this great opportunity and loses a 50-50 bet...***you know***.

This ようじゃ is a colloquial way of saying [ようでは](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-you-dewa-meaning/) ("if something/someone is like ～"). ね is a filler particle, but it's probably working like "you know (what I mean)" here. It depends on the context, but usually something like "he was doomed to fail in the first place" is implied.